# Fluentd ssl verify false option

Tags: ssl, fluentd

I am running fluentd with the option verify ssl set to false. I am having a hard time figuring out if the traffic is still encrypted using this option. From what I can gather it is still encrypted. As the name would suggest, it just isn't verifying the certificate is legitimate and trusted. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

> it is still encrypted....it just isn't verifying the certificate is legitimate and trusted.

Yes, the traffic is still encrypted. Only, without proper certificate validation you cannot be sure that you are communicating encrypted with the expected system and not with some attacker impersonating the expected system. This attacker could for example sniff or modify the traffic as a man in the middle.

Not validating the certificate might be sufficient if you are in a network where only passive attacks are possible (i.e. traffic sniffing). If an attacker is able to mount active attacks (using ARP spoofing, DHCP spoofing, DNS spoofing...) then you cannot be sure that you talk to the correct system when not validating the certificate.